# Panel data - Creating a date variable from year and weeknumber as string

Tags: excel, date

I am writing with a query relating to panel data for historical prices. I am trying to create a date variable from an Excel file which contains year and weeknumber as a string. Is there a way to convert information available - year and week numbers (as string) into Stata or Excel recognisable dates? Thanks very much.

```
year    weeknum           Price 1   Price 2 
1890    2nd week in Jan   76        90  
1890    3rd week in Jan   76        90  
1890    4th week in Jan   76        90  
1890    2nd week in Feb   76        90  
1890    3rd week in Feb   76        90  
1890    4th week in Feb   76        90  
1890    2nd week in March 76        90  
1890    3rd week in March 80        94  
1890    4th week in March 80        94  
1890    5th week in March 80        94
```

[image: Data picture]

Comment: Which day of the week do you want?

Comment: And it will not be able to be a true date in Excel.  True dates do not go past 1900 in the past.

Comment: Thanks Scott, apologies - I am new to this forum. Defintion of week - I simply need the week to be correctly noted. The precise day of week - whether weeks start on Sunday or Monday is not an issue - either would work for me. Is Excel unable to record dates prior to 1900? Thanks again.

Comment: That is correct Excel does not recognize dates prior to 1900.  Best you can do then is to create a text string that looks like a date in Excel.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.